# Include GitHub files into a remote website

Tags: api, github

What is the easier way to embed a GitHub README.md file into a remote website?

I would love to have a synchronized copy of the README file on a web page, I think GitHub pages don't allow users to do so, and I didn't find my answer in the GitHub API. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a solution to my problem: *[Using the GitHub API and PHP to Get Repository Information](http://davidwalsh.name/github-markdown)*, and [here](http://thinkphp.ro/apps/php-hacks/cache-function/github/) is a working demo.

Comment: I made a project based on the article above, you can se the source code here: https://github.com/raphaelbastide/Website-for-1962/

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of a copy you want if you want a file copy like in example.com/project/README.md or something displayed on a php page. If what you want is the first you can make a php script to fetch the file to your server. But if you want to have it on a php page you can use something like :

```
<?php
$url = "https://raw.github.com/USER/PROJECT/README.md";
$readme = file_get_contents($url);

print $readme;
?>
```

And this would be the fetch script I mentioned earlier

```
<?php
$url = "https://raw.github.com/USER/PROJECT/README.md";
$readme = file_get_contents($url);

$file = fopen('README.md','w');
fputs("$file","$readme");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: What you have posted is way of getting data from a repository using the API. I like to use file_get_contents and the raw file it makes it so much simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/

You can both retrieve and create blobs.